# Make screen scrollable?

Tags: android, scrollable

Im trying to make my screen scrollable, i looked around this site for quite a while without any success. I just need to know where im going wrong. Ive tried without scrollview and with, different sites tell me to do different things.
Essentially i want the screen scrollable for smaller devices to fit all the content.

```
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/SonucScrollView"   
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"          
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
     >          

<LinearLayout       
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@color/white" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.75"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    tools:context=".TourismActivity" 
    >  

    <LinearLayout       
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".15"
        android:orientation="horizontal" > 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".15"        
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey"/>

    </LinearLayout> 

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".6"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1.2" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"        
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:src="@drawable/abbeyleix" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:src="@drawable/longford" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:src="@drawable/tullamore" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:src="@drawable/athlone" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".9"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="3.7" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonTourism"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/laois"
                android:textColor="@color/blue" />
             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="Located in the heart of Ireland, Laois showcases the raw beauty of nature long forgotten."
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" >
            </TextView>




            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonTourism1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft = "10dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:text="@string/longford" />
             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="fill_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="Located in the heart of the lakelands, the endless beauty and rural charm of Longford makes for a great desination"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" >

            </TextView>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonTourism2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:layout_marginLeft = "10dp"
                android:text="@string/offaly" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="fill_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="Nestled in the bosom of Slieve Bloom Mountains and the Shannon River, Offaly offers a vast plethora of beauty."
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/red"
                android:textColorLink="@color/red"
                android:textSize="12sp" >

            </TextView>



            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonTourism3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft = "10dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"

                android:text="@string/westmeath" />

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="fill_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="Follow the tranquil Royal Canal as it meanders through Westmeath where the vast majesty of beauty knows no bounds."
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/red"
                android:textColorLink="@color/red"
                android:textSize="12sp" >

            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:background="@color/grey" />

    </LinearLayout>





</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `layout_weight` and `weightSum` from your "vertical" `LinearLayout` elements. It is causing the layout to scale to the height of the screen, so that there is nothing to scroll.

Ah, and @Selvin's comment may be required too, to make `linearLayout1` height "wrap_content".

Comment: do i remove the weightSum and weight from imageview and buttons aswell??

Comment: Yes. Remove it from anything that is laid out in the vertical orientation.

Comment: seems to be working, component placement all over the place now.

Comment: any way to use the weights and weightsums and still allow it to scroll??

Comment: Yes. If you make a "vertical" `LinearLayout` an exact height such as `android:layout_height="60dp"`, then everything inside can be weighted.

Comment: ok its just because i was using weights to make the app look the same on small android device and tablet. Once i did it your way the tablet app is tiny on the screen thats scrollable. You see that reaseon behind this scrollable screen idea is because i want text and it appears smaller on larger screens and vice-versa. My idea was to make the screen scrollable to allow larger text if you get me